# Nvarchar to varchar to nvarchar characters conversion

Tags: sql-server, alter-table, collation, encoding, unicode

I had a table filled with some greek text rows as `nvarchar(2000)`.

Lately, I altered the type of the column to `varchar(4000)` but I realized that some greek characters were shown as question marks.

So, I tried to change back to `nvarchar(4000)` in order to fix it as I suppose that the characters' unicode still remains the same.

I am just wondering, is there any way to fix this instead of restoring the backup I created before altering the table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no way to "fix" the data because the data is no longer there. When you converted to `VARCHAR`, the underlying values for each character were changed into the ASCII value for `?`. This is not a display issue, those characters are now physically a regular question mark. You will need to do a restore from a backup, unfortunately.

The following example code shows that once a Unicode character is converted to `VARCHAR` (assuming the Code Page denoted by the Collation does not support that character), that it becomes a regular 'ol question mark, and forever shall it remain as such:

```sql
DECLARE @Character NCHAR(1) = NCHAR(0x3525);
SELECT @Character AS [TheCharacter],
       UNICODE(@Character) AS [DecimalCodePoint],
       ASCII(@Character) AS [DecimalValueOfVarchar],
       UNICODE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @Character)) AS [ConvertToVarchar], 
       UNICODE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @Character)))
             AS [ConvertToVarcharAndBack], 
       ASCII('?') AS [VarcharQuestionMark],
       UNICODE(N'?') AS [UnicodeQuestionMark];

-- 㔥    13605   63  63  63  63  63
```

The following example shows an instance of a Unicode character that is highly doubtful (at least at this time) to be supported in most fonts, hence it *appears* as a square box, but the `UNICODE` built-n function shows that the underlying code is still the correct Unicode Code Point:

```sql
SELECT NCHAR(0xABBF), N'ꮿ', UNICODE(N'ꮿ');

-- ꮿ    ꮿ   43967
```

The actual character can be seen here: [Cherokee Small Letter YA U+ABBF](http://unicode-table.com/en/ABBF/). *This* is a display issue, and many characters that are not represented in various fonts will display in the same manner without altering the actual value of the character, but they are still distinct characters.

Answer (score 2):

I was hoping to find a way to cheat, but it appears that srutzky is correct.
Here's a script to prove (I think) underlying data change:

```
--build and populate table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #t

CREATE TABLE #t
(txt nvarchar(1))

INSERT #t
VALUES
(N'Γ')

--show how it's stored
SELECT txt,CONVERT(varbinary,txt)
FROM #t

--Alter and show
ALTER TABLE #t
ALTER COLUMN txt varchar(2)

SELECT txt,CONVERT(varbinary,txt)
FROM #t

--And again
ALTER TABLE #t
ALTER COLUMN txt nvarchar(1)

SELECT txt,CONVERT(varbinary,txt)
FROM #t
```